# How to obtain pages which were loaded during active session when browser closes?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I delevop firefox extension.

I can obtain those pages with analyzing attributes "pending" and "unread":

```
gBrowser.tabContainer.getItemAtIndex(i).getAttribute("pending");
```

or

```
gBrowser.tabContainer.getItemAtIndex(i).getAttribute("unread");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/pending

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/unread

But I can't do same when browser closes (I catch "unload" event). Each times attributes are empty. May be it's wrong way?

Comment: Generally you can't rely on being able to do much in the "unload" event. The information you need has probably already been removed as part of the unload process. So although I don't really have an answer for you, I'd suggest looking into whether there are any alternative events (that might occur earlier). Failing that, you'll probably need to rethink your approach - perhaps keeping track of this data within your extension while Firefox is still running.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to find other events like as "beforeunload", "hide": [Window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) But I cant do so that event was  handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to on start of session start recording page loads. Then on unload you have them available to you. Do you know how to do this or do you need help with this?

Comment: Thank you. I have already implemented the updating structure. I listen "DOMContentLoaded" and "TabClose". When browser closes there are all active pages.